# DIY package that can be superceded by official update?

Tags: package-management, ppa, versions, checkinstall

There is a utility package available in the official apt repo, and I have installed it, but the version there does not contain a feature I need. As far as I can tell, there's no third-party repo supplying this new version (yet, anyway).

I'm comfortable using `checkinstall` to semi-manually install packages from source, or publishing to my own PPA. However, in this case, I would like to install the new version (which in this case happens to be version `1.14`) myself, but if and when an official update version ≥ `1.14` appears, I'd like to switch back to it without further intervention.

Can I do this by using `checkinstall` to create a local package of, say, version `1.13-99`? And will that be sufficient? Do I need to make the `checkinstall`-generated package’s metadata fields match the original's? Does using a package from my PPA act any differently from a `checkinstall` package in this respect?

> *I just did an experiment, and a PPA package with a newer version than an installed official one* does *get upgraded in the course of regular package upgrades. But I don’t see an easy way to test this with a `checkinstall` package.*

I could, of course, ignore `checkinstall` *or* my PPA, and instead install the new version of the utility into */usr/local/bin/* or *~/bin/* (which, being earlier in my `PATH` than the system directories, will be picked instead of the official install), and then I will *install* the newer version just by leaving the old (`1.12`, in this case) installed version alone. Then — *if I notice it,* — I can simply delete the copy in *~/bin/*, and then I’m back to the standard release channel.

But the issue is that I'm very unlikely to notice the update—I can't (or at least, don't) scrutinize every updated package, except for security patches and kernel patches. If I `apt-mark hold` the package, I *might* notice `The following packages have been kept back:`, buh I might not. If creating a `checkinstall` or PPA package with an artificially-lowered version number will work without my attention, it would be a much better solution.

Comment: An exact answer would require posting the full name of the Ubuntu package in question. If it's just whatever-1.13 then name the new one whatever-1.14~ppa which is a lower version than whatever-1.14

Comment: @doug Could you elaborate on this? Because how to do it for a specific package is not a particularly useful question. This isn’t the first time I’ve run into this issue; I’m asking because it’s come up more than once and I’d like to know the best practice for proceeding. What about one package versus another would make the answer different?